# Boost Container vs Boost multi_index_container

Tags: performance, boost, containers, boost-interprocess, boost-multi-index

What are the advantages of the boost::container class compared to boost::multi_index_container one?

They can both store their data in shared memory and work with Boost.Interprocess (crucial for me), and multi_index_container seems to provide more advanced functionality.

What features of container are missing from multi_index_container?

References:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/creation.html#special_allocator
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/container.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Container is not a single class but rather a collection of containers with various interfaces (though all of them based on STL conventions) and internal data structures, so a feature comparison with Boost.MultiIndex's `multi_index_container` really depends on what particular container you're interested in. Anyway, all of the containers in Boost.Container *and* `multi_index_container` can be placed in shared memory with Boost.Interprocess, but if this is the only non-standard feature you look for I guess you probably want to stick with `boost::container::set` or similar.